# Typescript: Define a type T such that T & {'a': any} == R

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, union-types

I've been struggling with a somewhat interesting problem in defining types.
As I'm learning TS, Please keep in mind that I'm also looking for an explanation or a reference to one.

As per the title, I have a function defined as:

```
function make<ChildObj extends ParentObj, ParentObj, Missingkey extends string>(
  parentObj: ParentObj,         // Only 1 key is missing to make ChildObj become ParentObj
  missingKey: MissingKey,
): ChildObj {
  const missingKeyValue = Math.random();
  doSomething({ // doSomething expects the first parameter to be of type ChildObj
    ...childObj,
    [missingKey]: missingKeyValue
  });
}
```

Usage example:

```
type ParentObj = {a: any};
type ChildObj = {a: any, b: any};

make<ParentObj, ChildObj, 'x'>({a: 0}, 'x') // Invalid because ParentObj & {'x': any} is not ChildObj

make<ParentObj, ChildObj, 'b'>({a: 0}, 'b') // Valid
```

So in short, I need to constrain `missingKey` to be the 1 `keyof` `ChildObj` that `ParentObj` doesn't have.

Thanks in advance for any help and explanation!

Comment: The title is very misleading

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify Child as generic parameter. The function `make` just returns an intersection of `Parent` and an object with the extra key.

```js
function make<T extends object, K extends string>(parent: T, key: K) {
    return {
        ...parent,
        [key]: Math.random(),
    } as T & { [P in K]: number };
}

const a = make({x: 1}, 'y'); // type: {x: number} & {y: number}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mihályi, unfortunately that won't work because `make` is part of a class that works with `ChildObj` and `make` then calls another function which expects the type `ChildObj`. I didn't specify this in the initial question (edited) as I realise now that it's relevant towards the answer

Comment: I am not sure, how can `doSomething` expect any type, if `make` does not specify any type constraint